# Manipulating parametrized variables in a Jenkins SVN url

Tags: regex, jenkins

Looking for some tips on how to edit the REVISION variable in a SVN URL, specifically execute a substring on ${REVISION} to derive exact name of the SVN branch.

> *https://server/path/myproject${REVISION}*

Do these variables follow bash syntax or Java expression syntax or something else altogether?

Comment: It looks like it is not documented: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-45199

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging from the [source the of SVNLogFilter](https://github.com/jenkinsci/subversion-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/hudson/scm/DefaultSVNLogFilter.java) 
on Github, the Jenkins SVN plugin does not use bash but `java.util.regex.Pattern` regular expressions.

[Java regex pattern documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.ht%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bml).

Comment: Not a true solution, but I guess there is no true solution. Thanks for guiding me here. This is partly an acceptable answer for this question!